# jquery selectmenu idand the selected value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to get the id and the selected value of the selectmenu together. Is there any way for this? I tried but I cannot get these two simultaneously.

```
$('#form1').submit(function () {
 $('.required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
    var input = $(this).val();
    if (!input) {
      $(".ui-selectmenu").addClass( "required" );
      var msg = input.attr('title');
      alert(msg); --- This will alert empty.
      alert(input.attr('id'));
      $(".ui-selectmenu").after('<ul class="error"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>');
    }
 });
});
```

I can get the title or id of the selected value using

```
$('.required')find(":selected").each(function(){
 var input = $(this).val();
 alert($(this).attr('title')); ---- This will alert the title.

});
```

HTML

```
<select id="test" name="test" class="required class1" title="Please select to continue.">
```

Selectmenu

```
$('select.class1:not(select.class2)').selectmenu({
style:'dropdown',
maxHeight: 300,
transferClasses: true
});
```

But I need to iterate through all the dropdowns and check if empty, If empty throw display error. That is why using `$('.required').filter(':visible')`

Could some body please tell me what I am doing wrong here.?

Comment: In either of your examples you don't appear to be trying to get the value. Can you show us your code for this?

Comment: Hi Nunners..Thanks for pointing that out..I just edited my code..

Comment: You are setting `input` to be the value of the dropdown. Not the actual dropdown object. Try changing : `var input = $(this).val();` to be `var input = $(this);` and then `if (!input) {` to be `if (input.val() != '') {`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.required').each(function(){
if($(this).val()=='')
 {             
         alert($(this).attr('title'));
 }
});
```

Comment: Hi Sanal, I want to get the title of the selectmenu when the value is null

Comment: Hi Praveen, Added the html. When the user does not select any value from select menu, it should display the error "Please select to continue." If the user has selected the value, then no error message.

Comment: @user1049057 I have edited the .each function can you check it now?

Comment: Can you make a Js-fiddle of your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `input` variable to be the dropdown object instead of the dropdowns value.

Try the following :

```
 $('#form1').submit(function () {
    $('.required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var inputValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        if (!inputValue) {
            $(this).addClass('required');
            var msg = input.attr('title');
            alert(msg);
            alert(input.attr('id'));
            $(this).after('<ul class="error"><li>'+ msg +'</li></ul>');
        }
    });
 });
```

Now it checks against `input.val()` and your `input` object is the dropdown object.

**EDIT:** <kbd>[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a53eT/2/)</kbd>

Comment: What part of it is not working? The check to see if the value is empty? The getting of the Title?

Comment: Yes..if i select value, then title is alerted correctly. But if I am not selecting a value, title is coming as null. and so I cannot display the error.. Hope u understand the problem

Comment: I've added a working JSFiddle to my answer, this checks if the selected value is null. If you require to check a value other than null then please specify that.

Comment: Hi Nunners..Thanks for the fiddle. It works fine..But some how my code is not working..My dropdown is selectmenu..So not sure if its coz of the selectmenu, always I am getting input.val() as empty. But if I use $(".required option:selected").val(); I am getting the value properly.

Comment: Updated my JSFiddle and my code to work with the method you mentioned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40954/discussion-between-user1049057-and-nunners)